# Last modification of a file

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying to retrieve as much information of the files on Git with JGit as possible.
With [getCommitTime](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html#getCommitTime()) I can get the time, when a files was commited. Is it also possible to get the time when a file has been modified/updated/edited? I haven't found something like getModifiedTime.

Comment: Git does not record modification timestamps. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085396/date-modified-in-file-system-does-not-change-when-switching-branches-in-git-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck. Git records the *contents* of a file in an object called "blob", and the *filename* in a tree object, but it keeps no record of *timestamps* associated with the file.

When you check a file out, the modification timestamp of the file now in your working tree is actually set to the current date and time shown by your kernel clock.

#### Why it's not such a bad thing

You probably use the `make` utility (or the likes of it) to automate your build. As you know, `make` relies on modification timestamps to figure out which targets (if any) must be built.

Let's imagine what could happen if Git did record (and restore upon checkout) modification timestamps of committed files. Let's assume you have a repository with only one tracked file, `foo`, which is the only dependency of a target called `bar`:

```
foo -> bar
```

Let's assume further that,

- your history consists of two commits:

  ```
  A -- B [HEAD=master]
  ```
- the modification timestamp of `foo` in commit `A` is "today", 9 am,
- the modification timestamp of `foo` in commit `B` is "today", 10 am.

You currently have commit `B` checked out, and you have run `make` at 10:05 am, so the build (`bar`) in your working tree is up to date. However, you decide that you want to go back to commit `A`, and create and check out a branch from there (possibly to take `foo` in a different direction):

```
git checkout -b other HEAD^
```

Your repo now looks as follows

```
A [HEAD=other]
 \
  B [master]
```

If you were to run `make` again, in order to build the version of `bar` corresponding to commit `A`, `make` would compare the modification timestamps of the tracked and currently checked out file `foo` (9 am) and that of the untracked file `bar` (10:05 am), and it would conclude that `bar` is up to date and doesn't need to be built again.

To force make to build `bar` again, you would have to `touch` foo. That be a hassle, and of course, the problem would get worse as the number of tracked `make` dependencies in your project increases.

So it's not such a bad thing that Git doesn't record and restore modification timestamps of tracked files upon checkout.

---

Relevant reading:

- [Date modified in file system does not change when switching branches in Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085396/date-modified-in-file-system-does-not-change-when-switching-branches-in-git-repo)
- [Restore file's modification time in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458042/restore-files-modification-time-in-git)
- [Checking out old file WITH original create/modified timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179722/checking-out-old-file-with-original-create-modified-timestamps)